# Strange error "Routes not defined"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel 5.4 and I can't get around this. I've added two routes in my view blade like this

```
<a href="{{ route('backend.blog.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Write post</a>
```

Then in my route web.php file I have

```
Route::resource('/backend/blog', 'Backend\BlogController');
```

In `HomeController@index` where I loading index page which has the button above, like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;

class BlogController extends BackendController
{
    protected $limit = 5;

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts     = Post::with('category', 'author')->latest()->paginate($this->limit);
        $postCount = Post::count();
        return view("backend.blog.index", compact('posts', 'postCount'));
    }
       ...

}
```

HomeController in Backend dir holds

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends BackendController
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.home');
    }
}
```

`backend.home` has the `a href` above which generates the error.. Why this happen?

Full error message

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
Route [backend.blog.create] not defined. (View: /var/www/blog/resources/views/backend/home.blade.php)
```

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list` in your terminal to check for the route names.

Comment: `route(..)`  is for named routes. A resource doesn't register any named routes.

Comment: @apokryfos, in fact resources have automatically generated names

Comment: In your route why you have the controller second and the fucntion first? `Backend\BlogController` is this a typo? controller goes as first argument and then the function

Comment: I'm following course but the problem is that the course is using `Laravel 5.2` and I'm using `5.4` .. some things are a bit different

Comment: @apokryfos exactly, resources should generate names and I see routes when I check `php artisan route:list` yet it didn't found them

Comment: use `url("/backend/blog/create")` a named route is when you define a route as `Route::get("/path/to/route", "controller@action")->name("this is the name");` this is not what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::resource('/backend/blog', 'Backend\BlogController', [
    'names' => [
        'create' => 'backend.blog.create'
    ]
]);
```

route() helper make named route

routing

```
Route::POST("/backend/blog/create", "Backend\BlogController@create")->name("backend.blog.create");
```

in view

```
{{ route('backend.blog.create') }}
```

Comment: @VLS Are you getting the same error when you do this or a different one as this should work?